# Пайтон парсинг HTML-документ с несколькими одинаковыми тегами

Tags: python, парсер

Всем привет, не могу понять как правильно обратиться к тегу span который мне нужен, чтобы он брал только  одну оригинальную цену на чай в карточках товара. Нашел способ обратиться по индексу тега, но span может быть больше 100 на сайте...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from time import sleep
import random
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

ua=UserAgent()
exel=pd.DataFrame()
domen="https://online.metro-cc.ru"
n,p,u,x,s,l,k=[],[],[],[],[],[],[]

for count in range(1,2):
sleep(3)
link=f"https://online.metro-cc.ru/category/chaj-kofe-kakao/chay?page={count}"
headers={"User-Agent": ua.chrome}
response=requests.get(link,headers=headers).text
bs=BeautifulSoup(response,"lxml")

name_chai=bs.find_all("span", class_="product-card-name__text")


price_chai=bs.find_all("span",class_="product-price__sum-rubles") #ЦЕНА ЧАЯ



card_url=bs.find_all("a",class_="product-card-photo__link reset-link")



for name,price,url in zip(name_chai,price_chai,card_url):
    n.append(name.getText())
    p.append(price.getText())
    u.append(domen+url.get("href"))
    print(price.getText()) # Выводит всё подряд включая скидки...
    #print(name.getText())
    #print(domen + url.get("href"))



for xarakteristika in u:
headers={"User-Agent": ua.chrome}
responce = requests.get(xarakteristika, headers=headers).text
bs = BeautifulSoup(responce, 'lxml')
xarakteristika_chai=bs.find("ul",class_="product-attributes__list style--product-page-full-list")
x.append(xarakteristika_chai.get_text())
#print(xarakteristika_chai.getText())


for opisanie in u:
headers={"User-Agent": ua.chrome}
responce = requests.get(opisanie, headers=headers).text
bs = BeautifulSoup(responce, 'lxml')
opisanie_chai=bs.find("span",class_="product-text-description__content-text")
s.append(opisanie_chai.get_text())
#print(opisanie_chai)



exel["Название"]=n
exel["Цена"]=p
exel["Сылка товара"]=u
exel["Характеристика"]=x
exel["Описание"]=s
exel.to_excel("./Парсинг_Метро.xlsx", index=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

link = "https://online.metro-cc.ru/category/chaj-kofe-kakao/chay"
response = requests.get(link)
bs = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
products = bs.find_all(class_="catalog-2-level-product-card")

product_data = []
for product in products:
    name = product.find(class_="product-card-name__text").text.strip()
    price = product.find(class_="product-price__sum-rubles").text.strip()
    url = product.find(class_="reset-link").get("href")
    product_data.append({'Название': name,
                         'Цена': price,
                         'Ссылка товара': 'https://online.metro-cc.ru' + url})

df = pd.DataFrame(product_data)
df.to_excel("Парсинг_Метро.xlsx", index=False)
```

Comment: Спасибо! Очень помогли